# Secure Socket From JSON Injection

Tags: javascript, json, security, sockets, websocket

I have done a chat with websockets. Here is how I have done it. When the user presses the enter key, the following JSON String is sent to server via websockets.

```
var chat_message = { 
    "type" : "chatmessage", 
    "conversation_name" : 'conversation-name',
    "conversation_id" : 'unique-conversation-id', 
    "sender" : 'name-id-and-user-name-of-sender', 
    "message" : 'messages-goes-here', 
    "time" : "7.02AM" };

socket.send(JSON.stringify(chat_message));
```

The server parses it and sends the messages to all the participants of the conversation.

Now I'm able to send the same JSON string from Javascript console in firebug, and obviously the message gets sent.

does this issue open a serious security hole? How I can stop it? I couldn't get an idea. I guess my implementation is completely wrong.

Comment: What threat are you trying to guard against?

Comment: I meant, someone can put in a fake Notification to some random user. The notification goes to the random user. How do I prevent this? Should I validate all the notifications coming through web sockets?

Comment: Your JavaScript is fine - you would need to validate on the server that the user has permissions to add messages to the particular `conversation_id`.

Comment: Ok, I thought validating all the messages coming through websockets will add a delay.